# ¿se puede interactuar con elementos traidos con php?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Cuando quiero interactuar con con este código en `jquery` no puedo crear eventos,
los eventos no se ejecutan. Se puede interactuar o tendré que elegir otra tecnología?

Si me expreso mal tratare de expresarme mejor en los comentarios.

**Código `ajax`:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "php/publicaciones.php",
    success: function (response) {
        $("#pablic").after(response);
    }
});
```

**Código `php`:**

```
  $verificar = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT para FROM amigos WHERE de = '".$_SESSION['id_use']."' ");

   while ($a = mysqli_fetch_array($verificar)) {

$rt = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM publicaciones WHERE usuario = '".$a['para']."' ");

while ($er = mysqli_fetch_array($rt)) { 

    $thy = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id_use = '".$er['usuario']."' ");

    while ($es = mysqli_fetch_array($thy)) { ?>

     <div class="cont-publicaciones">
        <div class="cont-img-publicacion">
            <div>
                <img src="perfiles/<?php echo $es['avatar']?>" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="cont-int-publicacion">
            <div class="ppol">
              <a href="perfil.php?id=<?php echo $es['id_use'];?>"><h6><?php echo ucwords($es['nombre'])." ".ucwords($es['apellido']) ?></h6></a>
            </div>

            <div class="cont-pu">
                <span>
                    <?php echo $er['contenido']?>
                </span>
            </div>
```

Comment: Por favor lee [ask], no se entiende tu duda

Comment: los elementos html que se ven, son traidos con ajax e incorporados al index.html, pero cuando quiero interactuar con ellos no pasa nada, cualquier evento que les ponga no se ejecutan, sinembargo a los elementos que ya estaban en el index.html si puedo interactuar con ellos

Comment: Me parece por aquí que te hace falta mucha teoría acerca de lo que puede hacer php, jquery y ajax, para que puedas aclarar tus dudas sobre qué hace cada cosa, lee la documentación oficial, no sé si solo estás copiando y pegando código ya que lo que dices se sale dentro de las posibilidades de lo que hace cada lenguaje.

Comment: lo que tendrias que hacer es traer el array de datos en formato json y las etiquetas html las tienes que tratar en tu funcion jquery de respuesta, y asi tratar los datos traidos desde el servidor, seria mejor practica que formar tu html desde el servidor.

Comment: Quizá deberías explicar con un mínimo ejemplo lo que quieres hacer, ni siquiera entiendo qué quieres decir con *interactuar* ¿? Tú puedes crear elementos dinámicos y asignarles de alguna forma un elemento que te sirva para escuchar acciones en esos elementos. Pero si no explicas las cosas con claridad es difícil poder ayudarte. Es tan simple como decirnos: *yo creo este elemento de forma dinámica y luego de crearlo necesito hacer tal cosa con él, creo el elemento aquí, intento asignarle esta acción, pero no hace nada o da este error, etc*.

Comment: @JoséGiovannySolísNiño la unicac solucion que pensaba era traer los datos en formato json o usar react con otro lenguaje de backend, pero me quedare con json, muchisimas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Cuando haces esto:

```
$("#pablic").after(response);
```

estás **añadiendo al DOM nuevos elementos. Esos elementos aún no tienen definido ningun listener de eventos de jQuery ni de JavaScript**.

A los elementos que ya vienen en el documento inicial y no se obtienen por Ajax, se les puede asociar un listener al final de la carga del documento. Este sería el caso más normal:

```
...
<body>
  ...
  <button class="boton">MI BOTÓN</button>
  ...


  <script>
    function onClickBoton() {
      alert("Has pulsado el boton");
    }

    $(function() {
      // Esto ocurre 1 vez cuando el documento está completamente descargado.
      $(".boton").on("click", onClickBoton);
    });
  </script>
</body>
...
```

Esto lo puedes hacer porque hay un elemento con clase "boton" que está desde que se recibe la respuesta HTTP del servidor.

Ahora, si el elemento es nuevo, porque se ha creado después de la primera respuesta del HTTP servidor (esto es, porque lo has creado mediante JavaScript como consecuencia de una respuesta AJAX, o por algún otro motivo); este elemento nuevo no va a tener asociado ningún listener.

Imagínate que tu función Ajax devuelve el HTML de un elemento con clase "boton" y tu lo añades al DOM con .after(). Este botón no funcionará porque no lo has registrado.

Esto lo puedes resolver en principio de dos maneras.

1. La primera forma y recomendada, sería que una vez que hayas recibido tu elemento del DOM, vuelvas asignar los listeners:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "php/publicaciones.php",
    success: function (response) {
        // Esto ocurre cada vez que se recibe respuesta de éxito de la llamada Ajax
        $("#pablic").after(response);
        $(".boton").off("click"); // Para evitar duplicar listeners
        $(".boton").on("click", onClickPulsarBoton);
    }
});
```

Si te decides a hacer como dice José Giovanny Solís Niño en los comentarios, y lo que haces es obtener solo datos crudos de tu servicio web, y después crear los elementos desde JavaScript, tendrías que seguir la misma estrategia: reactivar los listeners después de haber creado tus nuevos elementos del DOM.

2. Otra opción es que no asignes a los nuevos elementos eventos de jQuery, sino que la respuesta que generes desde el PHP te incluya los eventos inline. Por ejemplo, en vez de que tu fichero .php genere un botón así:

```
<button class="boton">MI BOTÓN</button>
```

Lo genere así:

```
<button class="boton" onclick="onClickBoton();">MI BOTÓN</button>
```

De esta forma, automáticamente tu botón tendrá el evento asociado en cuanto se añada al DOM.